# Convert Extent Report HTML file to PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying to convert Extent report HTML file to PDF, however i did not succeed.

Below is the code i tried.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper;

public class Demo 
{
public static void main( String[] args ) throws DocumentException,     IOException
{
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("pdf.pdf"));
document.open();
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document,new FileInputStream("html.html")); 
document.close();
System.out.println( "PDF Created!" );
}
}

Exception in thread "main" com.itextpdf.tool.xml.exceptions.RuntimeWorkerException: Invalid nested tag head found, expected closing tag link.
at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorker.endElement(XMLWorker.java:134)
at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.endElement(XMLParser.java:396)
at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.state.ClosingTagState.process(ClosingTagState.java:70)
at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parseWithReader(XMLParser.java:236)
at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:214)
at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.parser.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:175)
at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.parseXHtml(XMLWorkerHelper.java:238)
at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.parseXHtml(XMLWorkerHelper.java:210)
at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.parseXHtml(XMLWorkerHelper.java:183)
at com.tib.controlStatements.Demo.main(Demo.java:22)
```

HTML File Link:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UrHafoit0rJuhTC0QRqCe9bC5PMpqIWS

Comment: And "i did not find any success" means exactly what? What happened and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: looks like error is there in your html file.can you add the html file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this example. You did not create the file and trying to fill it.

```
package sandbox.xmlworker;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import sandbox.WrapToTest;

@WrapToTest
public class D02_ParseHtml {

    public static final String HTML = "resources/xml/walden.html";
    public static final String DEST = "results/xmlworker/walden1.pdf";

    /**
     * Html to pdf conversion example.
     * @param file
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws DocumentException
     */
    public void createPdf(String file) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        // step 1
        Document document = new Document();
        // step 2
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
        // step 3
        document.open();
        // step 4
        XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document,
                new FileInputStream(HTML));
        // step 5
        document.close();
    }

    /**
     * Main method
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new D02_ParseHtml().createPdf(DEST);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Мат , I am still gettting the same error, i have attached the file for your reference.

Answer (score -1):

Finally found a work around for it. So what I have done is Added A css file with some adjustments in to the html and was able to covert to PDF and print with attached screenshots.